# Exchange 2007 resource calendar - how to display actual meeting title?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2007, calendar, mailbox

By default if you open a Resource calendar to see what is already booked in Outlook 2007 it will show times booked with the "user" that books them as the title.

Is there a way to set it so it displays the actual title of the meetings booked by default instead, even for users that aren't invited/organizing the meeting itself?

**For example:**

TheCleaner books a meeting in Room1 with title "Get stuff done"

If TheCleaner looks in Outlook at Room1 it shows booked as "Get stuff done"

If Noobie looks in Outlook at Room1 it shows booked as "TheCleaner"

-- I want it to show for Noobie the same as it shows for TheCleaner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe if you modify the Outlook permissions on that Calendar to allow Free/Busy searches to see "time, subject, location" instead of the default "time", this information will show up to all users.